# Trim sections between two chars in comment

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was looking on the internet for the fastest way of trimming parts of a string.
This is the input:

```
Hello /*test*/World!
```

This is the outcome I want to achieve:

```
Hello World!
```

---

I tried doing this with String.Remove, but I didn't succeed.

```cs
string input = "Hello /*test*/World!";
string output = input;
int index = output.LastIndexOf("/*");
int index2 = output.LastIndexOf("*/");
if (index >= 0)
{
    output = output.Remove(index, index2-3);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I would just use regular expression.

Comment: output = output.Remove(index, index2+2 - index);

Comment: Thank you Steve! This really solves my problem.

Comment: oneliner: input.Replace(Regex.Match(input, @"\/\*.*\*\/").Value, "")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*.

Add `using`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

then just use `Regex.Replace` with `@"/\*.*?\*/"` pattern:

```
string input = "Hello /*test*/World!"; 

// We replace each /* ... */ match with empty string
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"/\*.*?\*/", "");
// output: "Hello World!"
```

Pattern `/\*.*?\*/` explanation:

```
/\* - /*, note that * is escaped
.*? - any symbols but as few as possible
\*/ - */, note that * is escaped
```

Comment: Thank you, this is way better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I made with the help of Steve.

```cs
string input = "Hello /*test*/World!";
string output = input;
int index = output.LastIndexOf("/*");
int index2 = output.LastIndexOf("*/");
if (index >= 0)
{
    output = output.Remove(index, index2+2 - index);
}
```

Comment: As I have tried to tell, the best course to solve this kind of simple problems is through the help of the debugger. Visual Studio has an exceptional debugger and just passing a bit of time to learn how to use it will repay you tenfold all the time you have 'lost' studying it.

Comment: @AZ Software, check Dmitry Bychenko's answer. Regex, probably, fits more for your purpose and looks much simpler and compact.

Comment: Thank you all for your input and help!